# Fauna delete first item from intersection

Tags: javascript, facebook-fql, faunadb

I have a fauna db query that will return one match due to the combination of fields being unique:

```
await faunaClient.query(
  Intersection(
    Match(Index('tokens_search_by_blacklisted'), false),
    Match(Index('tokens_search_by_token'), refreshToken),
    Match(Index('tokens_search_by_type'), tokenTypes.REFRESH)
  )
)
```

What I want to know is from here how can I delete the first item returned, I know theoretically I can paginate, lambda delete but I don't want to iterate. I would just like to delete the first value returned.

I know if you use Get it will get the first item from a set but sadly delete doesn't do this and I shouldn't have to get the object aka perform a read just to select the ref then delete.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Match`, the result is a set reference for an index-backed set. Such sets include a reference to the covered document, even if the index doesn't explicitly specify the `ref` field in the `values` definition.

Once you use `Intersection`, `Union`, or `Difference`, the resulting set only includes the fields defined in an index's `values` definition: the implicit `ref` field is lost.

In Fauna, sets are unbounded, so there aren't any concrete items to operate on until the set is materialized via `Paginate` or `Get`. So, you'll need to use one of those functions in order to retrieve the tuples from the intersection.

You can set the page size to 1 so that `Paginate` only returns one item. `Paginate`'s implementation returns as soon as it has a page full of results, so it performs pretty well.

You'll need to be sure that the tuples in the `Intersection` result includes the document reference to delete, or you won't be able to delete.